# What's the difference between kyōshi and sensei?

Tags: word-choice

I am looking up the word for teacher and I see *kyōshi* and also *sensei*.

Can someone tell me the difference between these two translations?

Comment: This question has been asked [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40406/what-is-the-difference-between-%e5%85%88%e7%94%9f-and-%e6%95%99%e5%b8%ab). Can you read *hiragana* and (some) *kanji*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

教師 (kyoushi) is an objective word for a teacher, while 先生 (sensei) is honorific. Formally, you would use 教師 to speak about teachers in general, or to describe yourself, and 先生 to honour specific teachers; in informal communication, however, people often use 先生 as the general term.

Another matter: certain people such as doctors and lawyers are also called 先生, but they're obviously not 教師.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  Quick question, if writing in Romaji would it be Kyoushi or Kyōshi ?  I am a bit confused about the rules for Romaji

Comment: @Alan There are different systems for romanization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese *kyōshi* is Hepburn. *kyoushi* is strictly speaking none of Hepburn, *Nihon-shiki*, *Kunrei-shiki*, but because it is difficult to input, *ō* is often typed *ou* (so I guess *kyoushi* could be *wāpuro rōmaji*). In any case, *kyoushi* is unambiguously きょうし, so even if it doesn't belong to a particular system, it's a clear way of transliterating it.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Generally if I'm timing in Japanese, I type 'kyousi'. Giving Romanizations I use 'kyoushi' though.